# How does 2-legged oauth work in OAuth 2.0?

Tags: oauth-2.0, 2-legged

In OAuth 1.0, 2-legged is pretty easily: Simply send the request as usual and omit the `access_token` header.

Things seems to have changed in OAuth 2.0 (drastically, as I found out today :)). In OAuth 2.0, the request no longer has headers such as the nonce, consumer key, timestamp etc. This is just replaced by:

```
Authorization: OAuth ya29.4fgasdfafasdfdsaf3waffghfhfgh
```

I understand how 3 legged authorizations work in OAuth 2.0 and the application flows. But how does 2-legged work in 2.0? Is it possible to design an API that can support both 2-legged and 3-legged OAuth 2.0?

I have been searching for information regarding this, but I have been finding a lot of stuff on 2-legged for 1.0 and almost nothing for 2.0.

Comment: agree with you, there is enough information for 3-legged oauth2.0,  or 2-legged oauth 1.0, but hardly anything for 2-legged oauth 2.0.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

After lots of research, I discovered that `client_credentials` grant type is for this scenario. Once you punch this term into google, you can find loads of very helpful resources.

This is the normal flow for 3-legged OAuth 2.0 (we want the user to sign in):

Assume we have the following endpoints in our app for authentication:

```
/oauth/auth

/oauth/token
```

Normally (for authorization code grant), we direct the user to `/oauth/auth?state=blah&client_id=myid&redirecturl=mysite.com/blah`

Then upon authentication, the user is redirected to `mysite.com/blah?code=somecode`

We then get `somecode` and exchange it for a token using `/oauth/token?code=somecode&client_id=myid&client_secret=mysecret`

We can then use the token to make calls.

---

This is the application flow for `client_credentials` to implement 2-legged OAuth 2.0, which is markedly simplier:

- In this approach, we do not need to perform any authentication.
- We simply POST to `/oauth/token` with the following form data:

  ```
   grant_type=client_credentials&scope=view_friends
  ```

Note that scope is optional. The endpoint then directly returns an access token for us to use (no refresh token is provided). Since no refresh token is provided, when the token expires, you will need to reauthenticate and ask for a new one.

This leads to the following caveats:

- Use this only for (very very) trusted applications such as internal applications.
- You need to devise your own way to authenticate. For instance, the [RFC's example](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-31#section-4.4.2) uses basic auth.

Another solution is to use JWT (JSON web tokens) like the [google OAuth API](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount#libraries). It is a very complicated process, but there exists numerous libraries for generating your JWT. You then post the following form data (url encoded of course):

```
grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer&assertion=generated_jwt
```

This is posted to `/oauth/token` to get your token.

---

As for the question of **whether you can create an API that supports 2-legged and 3-legged OAuth 2.0**, **Yes, it is possible**.

Then `/auth` endpoint is only used when users need to authenticate against the service.

In the `/token` endpoint, simply check the value of `grant_type` in the GET parameters for `urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer` if using JWT or `client_credentials` for client_credentials.

Note that when generating the client_id and client_secret to give to the user, if you are supporting multiple `grant_types`, ensure that you have a database column to store what type of grant type the id and secret was generated for. If required to have multiple grant types per user, generate a different set of credentials for each grant type.

Comment: If you want you can also check Google's implementation. For instance the developer experience is documented here: https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation And yes basically using client credentials and special 'service accounts' that you delegate domain wide access to.

Comment: Hello Nivco, I am working on a Google API related project, and didn't find enough information/knowledge about 2-legged oauth 2.0.  Your link above really helps ,however, my question is: what about the Google calendar api, google contacts api and gmail IMAP XOAUTH?  Do they support 2-legged oauth2?  thanks

Comment: For more information about Google's 2-legged OAuth2 implementation you can also check out the following  link:https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount. 

Furthermore, access tokens obtained through Google's 2-legged OAuth2 are supported by all Google APIs (including calendar, contacts, etc), for more info on this see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20127114/which-google-apis-support-oauth2-domain-wide-delegation/20135458#20135458.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can also check out Google's implementation of [2-legged OAuth2](http://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount) (I believe this documentation has been published only recently).

The [Google Drive SDK delegation docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation) should also help understanding Google's 2-legged OAuth2 implementation.